# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Updating an Item of a task list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, exception

I am trying to update multiple items of a task list in a loop. But when my workflow reaches the step "**Update an Item**", it throws an exception "value does not fall within the expected range" while updating the first item itself. Couldn't make out why this is happening. Any suggestions are most welcomed.

The field I am trying to update is "Assigned To". Furthermore there's another workflow which creates the items in the Task List before they get updated.

User that runs the workflow should have access to the Task List item I am trying to update as I made him task process owner for this task beforehand.

**UPDATE**

The tasks were created using a 2010 workflow, so if I update any item of tasks List using a 2010 workflow it works fine. Catch is now if I try updating using a 2013 Workflow, it doesn't work.

Comment: We've got not that much information on this issue. What kind of field are you trying to update with what kind of value?

Comment: The field in task list is of datatype "person or group", I am trying to update this field with a value entered by user of datatype again person or group. (Form initiation parameter - returned as Login name)

Comment: Ok, Im just running a quick workflow test on my environment right now as I think that I usually use user id rather than login name but will have to confirm first the login name approach fails for me.

Comment: Quick update - I've done as you described (updating list item in Task list, using Login Name) and failed to reproduce your issue, it worked fine. Does it fail for you for all users or just some? Does it happen on other lists as well?

Comment: See I am trying to update the Field "Assigned to".There is another workflow which creates these tasks in "Workflow Tasks". I made one User 'A'   the task process owner for this task within the same workflow. Now the next workflow using which I am trying to update the item: SPD logged in user is the same user, USER 'A', so what I feel is that this workflow should have the right to update items in this task list.

Comment: Ok, let me check - I was updating a column of type Person I created on the task list.

Comment: I've done the same - updating the Assigned To field in task list item worked. Not entirely sure why you are having a problem with that but "value does not fall within the expected range" sounds like rights issues alright but you already mentioned that user has access to the task list. Could you see what kind of permissions said user has on mentioned task list using "Check Permissions" ribbon button when you are looking at the list permissions?

Comment: Observations made(Update) : The tasks were created using a 2010 workflow, so if I update any item of tasks List using a 2010 workflow it works fine. Catch is now if I try updating using a 2013 Workflow, It doesn't works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45399/discussion-between-cthulhubutt-and-mohd-tahir).

Answer (score 1):

**I were able to achieve it this way:**

As I were able to update an item in the task list using 2010 workflow, so I did this by triggering another list workflow within the same 2013 workflow. I passed the appropriate parameters for the 2010 workflow for each iteration of the loop. Now I could achieve this workaround with the combination of a 2013 and 2010 workflow.